# Python script not waiting for user input when ran from piped bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, pipe

I am building an interactive installer using a nifty command line:

```
curl -L http://install.example.com | bash
```

The bash script then rapidly delegates to a python script:

```
# file: install.sh
[...]
echo "-=- Welcome -=-"
[...]
/usr/bin/env python3 deploy_p3k.py
```

And the python script itself prompts the user for input:

```
# file: deploy_py3k.py
[...]
input('====> Confirm or enter installation directory [/srv/vhosts/project]: ')
[...]
input('====> Confirm installation [y/n]: ')
[...]
```

**PROBLEM**: Because the python script is ran from a bash script itself being `pipe`d from curl, when the prompt comes up, it is automatically "skipped" and everything ends like so:

```
$ curl -L http://install.example.com | bash
-=- Welcome ! -=-
We have detected you have python3 installed.
====> Confirm or enter installation directory [/srv/vhosts/project]: ====> Confirm installation [y/n]: Installation aborted.
```

As you can see, the script doesn't wait for user input, because of the pipe which ties the input to the `curl` output. Thus, we have the following problem:

```
curl [STDOUT]=>[STDIN] BASH (which executes python script)
= the [STDIN] of the python script is the [STDOUT] of curl (which contains at a EOF) !
```

How can I keep this very useful and short command line (`curl -L http://install.example.com | bash`) and still be able to prompt the user for input ? I should somehow detach the stdin of python from curl but I didn't find how to do it.

Thanks very much for your help !

**Things I have also tried**:

- Starting the python script in a subshell: `$(/usr/bin/env python3 deploy.py)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always redirect standard input from the controlling tty, assuming there is one:

```
/usr/bin/env python3 deploy_p3k.py < /dev/tty
```

or

```
/usr/bin/env python3 deploy_p3k.py <&1
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting the `STDERR` to `STDOUT` (with `2>&1`) ?

Comment: For completeness' sake. I couldn't tell from your description whether they had been redirected and/or whether they were required by the python script. In any event, the key to your specific question is `< /dev/tty`

Comment: Yes, the `< /dev/tty` was enough. Thank you very much !

Comment: FWIW, an alternative solution is `/usr/bin/env python3 deploy_p3k.py <&1`