# wait for user input when not `sys.stdin.isatty()`

Tags: python

When I try `some cmd | main.py`:

```
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    input() # how to wait for user input but not from pipe?
```

I am already read [Python script not waiting for user input when ran from piped bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769320/python-script-not-waiting-for-user-input-when-ran-from-piped-bash-script), but I cannot found `/dev/tty` in windows and **handle it in python code**.

Comment: If you call it like that, the pipe is connected to stdin of your python script, not the terminal. The user's input goes to `some cmd`.

Comment: @KlausD. It must be some way to get `/dev/tty` as stdin direct.

Answer (score 1):

*I cannot found `/dev/tty` in Windows and handle it in python code.* It could be `CON` or `CON:`

Here's my python script which accepts any combination of inputs from ***pipeline*** and from ***command line arguments*** as well as user's ***input from console***:

```
#! python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import sys

argv_tuple = []                                   # command line arguments
for arg in sys.argv:
    argv_tuple.append( arg )

pipe_tuple = []                                   # values from pipeline
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        pipe_tuple.append( line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r','') )
    sys.stdin = open('CON:', mode='r', encoding=sys.stdin.encoding)

inpt_tuple = []                                   # inputs from the console
invalue = input(' … your input (`Enter` to quit) … ')
while not invalue == '':                  
    inpt_tuple.append( invalue)
    invalue = input(' …                              … ')

#                                                 # publish the results
print( len( argv_tuple), 'arguments:', argv_tuple)
print( len( pipe_tuple), 'pipelines:', pipe_tuple)
print( len( inpt_tuple), 'kbd input:', inpt_tuple)
```

**Output**:

```
dir /b py*.py | python_stdin.py a "b & c"
```

> ```
>  … your input (`Enter` to quit) … foo
>  …                              … bar
>  …                              …
> 3 arguments: ['D:\\bat\\python_stdin.py', 'a', 'b & c']
> 2 pipelines: ['pythonprint.py', 'python_stdin.py']
> 2 kbd input: ['foo', 'bar']
> ```