# Get user input for a Python script ran from a bash script

Tags: python, bash

Tldr at the end

I have a simple Python script with a few functions, let's give this `main.py` as a minimal example :

```
import sys

def userAdd():
        var = input("Please type any input: ")
        print("My input is", var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

When I call :

```
python main.py userAdd
```

Everything works fine. The script runs, the Python console asks me for my input, and then edits the JSON file. Now I want this script to be executed everytime I edit a text file, let's say `myfile.txt` which for now only has this line :

```
foo
```

For this, I use [this bash script](https://superuser.com/a/634313) and changed the `"RUN COMMAND"` line with `python main.py userAdd` (let's call it `update.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

### Set initial time of file
LTIME=`stat -c %Z ./myfile.txt`

while true
do
   ATIME=`stat -c %Z ./myfile.txt`

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then
       python main.py userAdd
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

My problem happens here. Everytime the Python script is called from the Bash script, the input prompt shows up. I enter a value, and I get a `bash : <input> command not found`, which means the current tty I'm using isn't Python, but Bash

```
$ chmod +x update.sh
$ ./update.sh &
$ echo "bar" >> myfile.txt
$ Please type any input: test
bash: test : command not found
```

I tried a few things ([using /usr/bin/env and /dev/tty or <&1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25769320/9288741), or using `python -i`).

tldr; My Python script asks for a user input to update a file. When I run it directly from my bash terminal (*python main.py myfunction*), it works fine. When I run this Python script from a Bash script (which contains this same *python [...]* line) and type my input, I get a `bash <input> command not found`. This means that the terminal isn't Python's but Bash's. How can I get a Python terminal which will accept my input in this case ?

Comment: Wild guess here but does `sh -c "python main.py userAdd"` help out? maybe check $PATH too and make sure python path is set properly.  Something like `setenv PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"`

Comment: Part of your problem appears to be with your process running in the background `./update.sh &`.  Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286917/how-can-i-respond-to-a-prompt-within-a-shell-script-running-in-background

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, tried using the `sh` solution, but I faced the same issue unfortunately :/ I'll try to dig deeper in the background process possibility though, thank you for the idea !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be facing the same issue, here's how I solved it : I edited the line from `update.sh` invoking the Python script like so :

```
#!/bin/bash

### Set initial time of file
LTIME=`stat -c %s ./myfile.txt`

while true
do
   ATIME=`stat -c %s ./myfile.txt`
   if [[ "$ATIME" >= "$LTIME" ]]
   then
       /usr/bin/konsole -e /usr/bin/bash -c './main.py userAdd'
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

So this line ties me up to a specific terminal, but I think this could easily be bypassed by more advanced Linux users.

Then, when I run the script using `./update.sh &` and add this line to a cron, everytime I edit and close the file, a new terminal runs, asks for the input prints the results then closes (although for the sake of the example a `wait()` command should be added after the `print()`).